# Nextjs load styled components styles with delay

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have a question about styled components used with next js, more specyficly this versions:

```
"next": "12.3.1",
"styled-components": "^5.3.6"
```

**PROBLEM:**

When I reload localhost page for about 1 sec it shows me not styled html elements then change to styles written by me.

In my next.config.js I added to compiler styled-components

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  swcMinify: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Did you add _document.js in the pages directory ?

Comment: @ipikuka Yes i did but i dont do in _document.tsx noting with styled-components

Answer (score 2):

Here is my _document.js which works with styled components perfectly. I hope, this will solve the delay issue.

```js
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="Your content"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: This is a game-changer! should be the accepted answer